# Динамическая высота у iframe

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

В iframe будет подгружаться страница с другого домена. На этой странице можно будет просматривать разные категории товаров, поэтому нужно, чтоб фрейм растягивался или стягивался по высоте в зависимости от того, что в настоящий момент в нем отображается.

Вот здесь есть решение, но оно не работает, когда во фрейм подгружается страница с другого домена:
http://www.lost-in-code.com/programming/jquery-auto-iframe-height/

Comment: А вручную узнавать размер документа внутри фрейма не пробовали? Что-нибудь типа iframe.document.offsetHeight ?

Comment: Посмотрите приложения вконтакте - там эта проблема как-то решена=) И стороннее приложение может менять размер ифрейма в широких пределах.

Хотя... Там всё делается с запроса загруженной странички, которая свою высоту заведомо знает .-.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, что тут: http://www.lost-in-code.com/programming/jquery-auto-iframe-height/
совсем не jquery и не имеет к оному никакого отношения :)

```
function doIframe(){
    o = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for(i=0;i<o.length;i++){
        if (/\bautoHeight\b/.test(o[i].className)){
            setHeightIframe(o[i]);
            $(o[i]).load(function() { doIframe(); });
        }
    }
}

function setHeightIframe(e){
    if(e.contentDocument){
        $(e).height(e.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight + 35);
    } else {
        $(e).height(e.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight);
    }
}
```

doIframe() нужно вызвать после загрузки iframe, у которого класс будет стоять autoHeight.
Чтобы данный код работал, нужно использовать document.domain и выставлять его в соответствии с доменом, с которого грузится iframe, тогда браузеры будут "пускать" в iframe.